# How to add an action for a textfield in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

How to add an action for a textfield in NetBeans?

```
private void totalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) billing.getModel();
    model.addRow(new Object[]{code.getText(),itemname.getText(),rate.getText(),qty.getText(),total.getText()});

    String a = code.getText(); 
    String b = itemname.getText();
    String c = rate.getText();
    String d = qty.getText();

    int x = Integer.parseInt(rate.getText());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(qty.getText());
    int z = x * y;
    String r = String.valueOf(z);
    total.setText(r);
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you used the Netbeans Swing GUI Builder  the easiest way would be:

1. Select the JTextField in the Design view
2. Right-click for Pop-up Menu
3. Choose Events -> Action -> Action Performed.
    (This will  create a new function stub, setup the code to call it when the action occurs, and put the cursor in the source of the function. )
4. Copy contents of your function above  into the newly created function, or call your function above from within that function.

It is also possible to  select the textfield, select Properties, switch to the Events tab, and edit the Field for actionPerformed to specify your existing function.